# Using randomforestclassifier to predict unknown categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use randomforestclassifier to predict unknown categorical variables in a [stroke prediction dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/fedesoriano/stroke-prediction-dataset?resource=download) Specifically, I am trying to replace the unknown values in the smoking status column using a prediction model. However, although my code runs correctly, the dataset doesn't change at all. Could you explain how I could fix this issue?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

```
 raw_data = pd.read_csv('/Users/name/Desktop/CompSci_Projects/Stroke_Prediction_Model/dataset/healthcare-dataset-stroke-data.csv')
 data = raw_data.copy(deep=True)
 data.interpolate(method='linear', inplace = True)

 from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder 

 data['gender'] = data['gender'].astype('category') 
 data['ever_married'] = data['ever_married'].astype('category') 
 data['work_type'] = data['work_type'].astype('category') 
 data['Residence_type'] = data['Residence_type'].astype('category') 

 data['Gen_new'] = data['gender'].cat.codes 
 data['evm_new'] = data['ever_married'].cat.codes 
 data['wktp_new'] = data['work_type'].cat.codes
 data['restype_new'] = data['Residence_type'].cat.codes  

 # Create an instance of One-hot-encoder 
 enc = OneHotEncoder() 

 # Passing encoded columns 

 enc_data = pd.DataFrame(enc.fit_transform( 
 data[['Gen_new', 'evm_new', 'wktp_new', 'restype_new']]).toarray()) 

 # Merge with main 
 data = pd.concat([data.drop(data.columns[[1, 5, 6, 7]], axis=1), enc_data], axis=1)
 data

 smokestatus_unknown = data[data['smoking_status'] == 'Unknown']
 smokestatus_known =  data[data['smoking_status'] != 'Unknown']

 X = smokestatus_known.drop('smoking_status', axis=1).values
 Y = smokestatus_known['smoking_status'].values

 X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

 forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=45, max_depth=25, random_state=False, 
                            max_features=0.6, min_samples_leaf=3, n_jobs=-1)

 forest.fit(X_train, Y_train)
 y_pred_train = forest.predict(X_train)
 y_pred = forest.predict(X_test)

 smokestatus_unknown = smokestatus_unknown.drop('smoking_status', axis=1, errors='ignore')
 smokestatus_unknown.columns = smokestatus_unknown.columns.astype(str)
 prediction = forest.predict(smokestatus_unknown)       
 smokestatus_unknown.insert(6, 'smoking_status', prediction)
 data
```

If it helps, I received this warning. UserWarning: X has feature names, but RandomForestClassifier was fitted without feature names
warnings.warn(

Comment: Hey There! Please consider reformatting your question and source code. Thanks

Comment: The warning is clear as to what it means. Your feature_set being used doesn't have the column names in it

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you execute this line, your variable is no longer the part referenced from data, but a brand new variable

```py
smokestatus_unknown = smokestatus_unknown.drop('smoking_status', axis=1, errors='ignore')
```

If you want to write the modified `smokestatus_unknown` back to data, you should execute

```py
data.loc[data['smoking_status'] == 'Unknown', 'smoking_status'] = smokestatus_unknown
```